# How to specify task pod resources in Kubeflow Kale

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, kale, kubeflow-kale

Is it possible to specify the pod resources (memory and CPU requests and limits), for a task in a kubeflow pipeline created with Kale?

To provide more details, when writing the kubflow pipeline in python using the DSL, I can specify the task pod resources as follows:

```
    task1 = (
        train_op(...)
        .set_memory_request('600M')
        .set_memory_limit('1200M')
        .set_cpu_request('700m')
        .set_cpu_limit('1400m')
    )
```

Is it possible to do the same with Kale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, setting pod resource requests and limits for each task in the kubeflow pipeline is not possible with Kale. The best alternative is to set [default resources for the namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-default-namespace/), which will set the pod requests and limits for all tasks in the kubeflow pipeline.